# Array function not working on a JavaScript array created from element text

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have the following element, that when clicked on calls the a JavaScript function response(tag). I pass the element "rops" itself to the function.

```
<li><div class="rops"><span class="rops-text"> tag2 </span></div></li>
<li><div class="rops"><span class="rops-text"> tag2 </span></div></li>
```

So when I click on one of these elements it adds them to an array. But now array functions work for that array, and they do for a normally created array. See the following working case and not working case:

They work if I create an array my self:

Working case:

```
var checkA = [];
checkA[0] = "tag1";
checkA[1] = "tag2";

alert(checkA.indexOf("tag2")); //Gives me correct answer.
```

Not-working:
Array created like this:

```
response(tag) {

 myArray[i] = String($(tag).text()); //at current point has ["tag1", "tag2"]

 //But if i do the same
 alert(myArray.indexOf("tag2")); //Gives me -1 (similar for other array function).
```

So in short, creating an array using element text cause the array functions not to work. Can anyone please help with this. I am not sure why this is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: In your `response` function, how is `i` getting set?  In the snippet you have, it isn't, so it would be `undefined`, which isn't a numeric index.

Comment: Hi, the value of i is properly getting set. I just didn't enter all the code here. At that point if i do "alert(myArray)" it will show me "tag1, tag2" so they have been added to the array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function result(tag){
   myArray = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
   alert(myArray.item('tag').innerHTML);
}
```